# Difference between the rbegin and the end function in standard library

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have an implementation of a map where the ID is being stored as value and marks as key. This enables me to take advantage of the auto sorting in maps and lets me identify the ID of the element with highest marks.

```
for(map<int, int>::iterator i = marks.begin(); i != marks.end(); ++i)
    cout << i->first << "\t" << i->second << endl;
cout << marks.rbegin()->second << endl;
cout << marks.end()->second << endl;
```

produces this output:

```
312 3
420 4
512 2
752 1
1
420
```

The input sequence was the increasing order of values. Why does `end()` not display "1" but instead displays the key of the last pair inputted? What's the difference between `rbegin()` and `end()`?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: Regarding your request for formatting feedback: see my edits :-) Don't use pictures of text.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`rbegin` is actually the last element of your container.
`end` is *one past* the end of the container.

So `marks.end()->second` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Ah! That explains it. Thanks!

Comment: Also, `rbegin()` and `rend()` return a reverse iterator, which [works backwards compared to normal iterators](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8fcf0408635e5cc8).